# JDBI: How to manage reconnection after disconnection

Tags: database, dropwizard, jdbi

Using dropwizard with JDBI, by now if a cut the DB connection and restore it, requests don't work anymore after.

My database config is:

```
database:
  driverClass: org.postgresql.Driver
  user: ${USER}
  password: ${PASSWORD}
  url: ${URL}
  properties:
    charSet: ${CHARSET:-UTF-8}
  maxWaitForConnection: ${MAX_WAIT_FOR_CONNECTION:-1s}
  validationQuery: ${VALIDATION_QUERY:-"SELECT 1"}
  validationQueryTimeout: ${VALIDATION_QUERY_TIMEOUT:-3s}
  initialSize: ${INITIAL_SIZE:-8}
  minSize: ${MIN_SIZE:-8}
  maxSize: ${MAX_SIZE:-32}
  checkConnectionWhileIdle: ${CHECK_CONNECTION_WHILE_IDLE:-false}
  evictionInterval: ${EVICTION_INTERVAL:-10s}
  minIdleTime: ${MIN_IDLE_TIME:-10s}
  removeAbandoned: ${REMOVE_ABANDONNED:-true}
  removeAbandonedTimeout: ${REMOVE_ABANDONNED_TIMEOUT:-10s}
```

I notice that if initialSize = minSize = maxSize = 1 then the connection is restored, but I need more connections.

Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

add the configuration
**checkConnectionOnBorrow: true**
This will validate the connection each time the object is borrowed from pool and re-connects to DB